# ¿Como restar el total de repeticiones entre dos tablas?

Tags: mysql

Buen día,

Tengo este query que me trae el total de las veces que se repite el usuario el mes anterior de la tabla "megusta", para así sacar el total por usuario de cuantos me gusta a obtenido el mes anterior.

```
SELECT usuario, COUNT(1) AS total 
FROM megusta tp WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
GROUP BY tp.usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Pero quiero agregarle que me reste el total de veces repetido de la tabla "nomegusta" y así sacar un total en concreto de "nomegusta" VS "megusta" y si el total es mayor o igualo a 50 que inserte en la tabla "premios" los usuarios que cumplieron esa condición.

La verdad no tengo mucha experiencia en MYSQL y ya intente varias veces como hacerlo pero no me sale, y pues también quería saber si lo que me falta se puede poner todo eso en una consulta?

Agrego como están compuestas mis tablas:

megusta

```
id, idRespuesta, usuario, fecha
```

nomegusta

```
id, idRespuesta, usuario, fecha
```

premios

`id, usuario, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin` <- este campo se insertaría una fecha a 30 dias a partir de la fecha inicio, es por eso que al cumplirse la condición de 50, insertaría a los usuarios en esta tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conociendo la estructura de las tablas, podría darte una mejor respuesta. Aún sin saber esto y entendiendo que:

- Tienes una tabla `megusta` y una `nomegusta`
- Ambas tienen una estructura similar y el mismo criterio para seleccionarlas

Podrías hacer dos consultas y unirlas con un `union`, la única particularidad que consideraríamos la cantidad de `nomegusta` en negativo: `COUNT(1) * -1  AS 'total'`, de forma tal de poder "netearlas":

```
SELECT  T.usuario,
        SUM(T.total) AS 'total_neto'
    FROM (      SELECT  usuario, 
                COUNT(1) AS 'total'
                FROM megusta
                WHERE   YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                    AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                GROUP BY usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 1

            UNION

            SELECT  usuario, 
                COUNT(1) * -1  AS 'total'
                FROM nomegusta
                WHERE   YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                    AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                GROUP BY usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    ) T
    GROUP BY T.usuario
    HAVING SUM(T.total) >= 50
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Patricio, nada mas me queda duda en T.total ya que en las tablas no tengo ningún campo que sea total, o a que se refiere con ese campo?

Comment: @sagitorr, si te fijas las dos consultas internas retornan un cantidad que hemos llamado mediante el alias de columna: total, luego lo usamos en una su consulta cuyo alias de tabla es T, de ahí sale T.total.

Comment: Ok, ya entendi, probé tu código pero me da como resultado 
`usuario total_neto 
cesarop        2
cesarr       16`  y realmente en la tabla me gusta "cesarr" tiene 16 y en no me gusta tiene 6, algo no esta haciendo la resta de los no me gusta

Comment: @sagitorr, No debería, si dejaste el `HAVING SUM(T.total) >= 50`, los usuarios que te debería recuperar son solo los que tiene de 50 para arriba.

Comment: El 50 lo modifique a 10 para ver cuantos usuarios me daba y ver que hiciera la resta de no me gusta, pero solo me da dos usuarios cesarop 2 y cesarr 16, pero revise realmente cuantos me gusta tiene y no me gusta, cesarop tiene 13 no me gusta y 3 me gusta, y cesarr tiene 16 me gusta y 6 no me gusta

Comment: Ya lo arregle @PatricioMoracho como estaba en una base de datos de prueba tenia unas fechas mal, me arroja a cesarr 10 y ya no me muestra a cesarop, entonces quiere decir que nunca me mostrara los usuarios que salgan con números negativos?

Comment: @sagitorr, perfecto!. Efectivamente así como está el having solo te mostrará aquellos que tienen un "saldo" positivo mayor o igual a 10

Comment: Disculpa @PatricioMoracho en este query me faltaría hacer un `insert` en la tabla premios de los usuarios que hayan cumplido la condición y estaba pensando en poner un `GO` después del `HAVING` y ahí decirle que inserte los seleccionados, se podría hacer así? o que me recomiendas, y mi duda también es, si los usuarios que salgan los inserta cada uno en una fila? o me insertaría todos en una sola fila? lo que quiero es que me inserte cada usuario por fila para ponerle a cada uno una fecha fin de 30 días dependiendo de la fecha inicio

Comment: Cada fila de esta consulta si la incorporas en un `insert`  será una nueva fila en la tabla. Revisa el el uso del [`insert into ... select ..`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho estoy probando el query y he notado que si el usuario solo tuvo me gusta no lo toma en cuanta, solo toma en cuenta los que hayan tenido me gusta y no me gusta

Comment: @sagitorr, revisa individualmente las dos consultas, que efectivamente los dos resultados para el usuario sean  lo que esperas, no ve la forma en que pueda fallar el union como comentas.